# How do you install grunt-contrib-qunit in Ubuntu server 12.04 64?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, gruntjs, qunit

I have a grunt project with the following npm dependancies:

- grunt-contrib-qunit
- grunt-contrib-compass
- grunt-contrib-jshint

I created an Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit server in VirtualBox VM (from an Ubuntu host) and ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ruby rubygems gcc python make
sudo gem install compass

wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.15/node-v0.10.15.tar.gz
tar -xzf node-v0.10.15.tar.gz
cd node-v0.10.15/
./configure 
make
sudo make install
cd ../
rm -Rf node-v0.10.1
rm node-v0.10.15.tar.gz 

sudo npm install -g grunt-cli
```

Supposedly that installed npm. Then I used git clone to clone a grunt project that I was using in CentOS (it all works in CentOS). Unfortunately when I ran grunt it failed when trying to run qunit with the following error:

> Running "qunit:dist" (qunit) task Testing
>   /home/testuser/myproject/test/index.html OK
>
> Running PhantomJS...ERROR
>
> > > In order for this task to work properly, PhantomJS must be installed locally
> > >       via NPM. If you're seeing this message, generally that means the NPM install
> > >       has failed. Please submit an issue providing as much detail as possible at:
> > >       https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-phantomjs/issues Warning: PhantomJS not found. Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

I even ran npm update from the grunt folder and it still has this error.

What am I missing?

*edit*
Please note the following facts:

1. This project works in CentOS without error.
2. This project has all of the plugin's installed locally using --save-dev
3. Overwriting the local installs by installing each dependency manually does not fix this issue.
4. Uninstalling and reinstalling each dependency manually does not fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it.

```
sudo apt-get install phantomjs
```

After running that it works.

I found that after reading this: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-phantomjs/issues/22

Answer (score 5):

You need to run `npm install` from the root of your project to install the npm dependencies.

[EDIT] - After doing some more research, and after replicating this issue on a basic Ubuntu 12.04 install, I've finally figured out this issue.

The dependency chain is as follows:

`grunt-contrib-qunit` >> `grunt-lib-phantomjs` >> `phantomjs`

Now the `phantomjs` package simply installs a local version of `phantomjs`, and provides a JS api wrapper around the bin application. The problem is that `phantomjs` has certain OS level dependencies, as mentioned in the [download page](http://phantomjs.org/download.html#linux):

*"... . It is however expected that some base libraries necessary for rendering (FreeType, Fontconfig) and the basic font files are available in the system."*

And this is the reason why the local phantomjs install failed. Actually, the error is very generic as the install completes successfully, but phantomjs is not able to run.

The `phantomjs` NPM module does not handle `phantomjs` dependencies (as `phantomjs` is not a proper NPM module).

To fix the issue in Ubuntu 12.04, you need to manually install the `phantomjs` dependencies by installing the font packages with the following command:

`sudo apt-get install fontconfig`

I have created a ticket on the 'phantomjs' NPM project to add a note about these dependencies to the README: https://github.com/Obvious/phantomjs/issues/80

Comment: Not true, I have all of my dependancies installed locally with npm install --save-dev. Running npm install on the grunt folder only causes and error when package.json is not found.

If you see the original issue I have this working flawlessly in CentOS. I don't use npm install and I don't need a packages.json. So unless the NPM in CentOS is radically different I doubt that I need to add a packages.json file.

Also, npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-qunit should solve install qunit, yet that still doesn't fix the PhantomJS error in Ubuntu.

Also, all of the other dependancies work in ubuntu.

Comment: Why aren't you using the package.json file? If you did `npm install PACKAGE --save-dev` then it will add the dependency to your package.json file. How can you possibly manage dependencies if you're not using the package.json file? You wouldn't have these problems if you did things right to begin with, as doing an `npm install` would install all package (and sub-package) dependencies, including phantomjs. Your application dependency chain is now broken. I suggest moving back to using a package.json file. Your 'solution' is more of a hack that a solution man. I'm trying to help you.

Comment: I have just tried that and it does not install PhantomJS. I still have to install that manually. So no, package.json does not solve the problem.

Comment: My apologies Bernard. The README on the grunt-contrib-qunit project states phantomjs will be installed locally, but there is another reason why it fails to run. I have updated my answer, please re-read if you're interested in the _actual_ issue.